# Facebook Quote Translation Informal Language

Tags: slang, reading-comprehension

I would like the following quote translated for me. It comes from my sister who is going through a tough time right now. Unfortunately, we grew up apart. I grew up in Oklahoma and she grew up in Tokyo. I am coming here because I do not know where else to turn for help.

Quote:

```
苦しくなっちゃったから、さようならを言おう
```

Comment: Who is she saying this to?

Comment: her boyfriend, i believe ex-bf now

Comment: any help on the translation? @l'électeur?
thanks for all the help in advance

Answer (score 1):

> As [the situation] has become so tough, let me say farewell [to somebody].